# CSS3 gradients looking crappy under Fx

Tags: firefox, css

In the subject I mentioned only Firefox, because for now it's the only browser I tested my code under, though it would be nice if someone could give me a generic solution :).

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(4, 4, 4));
```

Using above code I see... steps? :) I mean - it's not smooth, but very rectangular-ish, like that: lightgrey, a bit darker grey, light black, black instead of colors smoothly fading into each other. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have better color vision than I, my friend. It's way too dark for me to see a gradient at all. Anyway, here's the style to support all modern browsers, as it is today:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbeY3/1/

**CSS**

```
background:-moz-linear-gradient(rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(4, 4, 4));
background:-o-linear-gradient(rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(4, 4, 4)); /* Opera */
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(4, 4, 4)); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
background:-ms-linear-gradient(rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(4, 4, 4)); /* IE10 PP */
background:linear-gradient(rgb(30, 30, 30), rgb(4, 4, 4)); /* W3C */
```

Comment: It is because I simply used the colour values you provided. Here's my updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/zbeY3/1/

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this formula for FF:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, topvalue 0%, bottomvalue 99%); /* firefox */
```

**so, in your case:**

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(30, 30, 30) 0%, rgb(4, 4, 4) 99%);
```

Also, if you're interested, this is the group that I use to cover various browsers.
It's for a vertical gradient, from #999 to #000.

```
/* CSS Gradients */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999999 0%, #000000 99%); /* firefox */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#999999), color-stop(99%,#000000)); /* webkit */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#999999', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my gradient was not smooth (at least I think so :)) - it's because the difference between starting color, and ending color is too small. On a big surface it's very much visible, though if I create a 100x100px div, it's ok...